# causality identification in text with Python NLTK? (followed by subjectivity detection)

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I have been hoping to identify causal inferences manifest in short texts revolving around sporting events... For instance, if a sentences goes like "Ugggh, no way my team lost a point because the referee sucks!", "Home base!! Awesome cooperation!!", etc. I wish to first identify there is causal inference --- my team lost because the referee was not doing his job, or my team won because they cooperate perfectly, etc.

And on top of this identification task, I need extract objectivity/subjectivity score from the reasons/causes identified as above.

I was wondering, other than manually create a lexicon for such purposes, or train a simple classifier by gathering some appropriate training data, probably requiring human annotation, is there a better/quick workaround, preferably using Python (and NLTK?)?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a research problem. Not well-scoped for SO.

Comment: thanks for your comment! @erip, where would suggest I post this?

Comment: I'm not sure about where to post it. Typically for novel research, people aren't going to want to give out solutions. I might dig around in literature.

Comment: ah, i see... should i delete this question then?

Comment: I am pretty confident that there is no "quick workaround" for this problem. It's a very hard NLP task. Even a carefully designed system won't deliver shiny results. And I suspect that, if you give the same texts to two human annotators, they will disagree on the right solution quite frequently.

Comment: thanks for your comment @lenz!